# Динамическая подгрузка данных по ajax и вывод на яндекс карту

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Ребят, приветствую! У меня есть код, который привёл ниже. Динамически нужно менять данные на карте, подгружая их из json.  Всё бы ничего вот только не подгружаются новые данные. Объясните, пожалуйста, зелёному почему вместо новых данных на карту выводятся старые данные? Буду признателен, если поможете оптимизировать.

````
    function init () {
        let myMap = new ymaps.Map('YMapsID', {
                center: [55.76, 37.64],
                zoom: 13
            }, {
                searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
            }),
            objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
                // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
                clusterize: true,
                // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
                gridSize: 32,
                clusterDisableClickZoom: true
            });

        // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
        // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
        objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
        objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
        myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "ajax/data.json",
        }).done(function(data) {
            objectManager.add(data);
        });

        $('#city').on('input', function(){
            if(city.length > 3) {
                 $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "ajax/data2.json",
                }).done(function (data2) {
                    myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();
                    objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#redDotIcon');
                    objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#redClusterIcons');
                    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
                    objectManager.add(data2);
                    myMap.controls.add(new ymaps.control.ZoomControl());
                    myMap.controls.add('typeSelector');
                    myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
                });
            }
        });
    } ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
ymaps.ready()
.done(function (ym) {
    var myMap = new ym.Map('YMapsID', {
        center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
        zoom: 10
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),
    firstButton = new ymaps.control.Button({
    data: {
        content: "Подгрузить новые метки"
    },
    options: {
        maxWidth: 180
    }});
    myMap.controls.add(firstButton, {float: 'left'});
    
    firstButton.events.add('click', function () {
        myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();
        
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager();

        myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/object_manager_options/data.json"
        }).done(function(data) {
            objectManager.add(data);
            var bounds = objectManager.getBounds();
            myMap.setBounds(bounds, {
            checkZoomRange: true,
            });
        });
    });

    jQuery.getJSON('https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/data_load_jquery/data.json', function (json) {

        var geoObjects = ym.geoQuery(json)
                .addToMap(myMap)
                .applyBoundsToMap(myMap, {
                    checkZoomRange: true
                });
    });
});
```

[Вот пример на jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shchedrin/ros0j75h/22/)

Comment: Дружище, спасибо огромное! То, что нужно! Допилил получилась конфетка.